# find + search huge files in short time

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, rhel, find

I am using the following find syntax in order to find huge `std*` files that are more then `1000M`.

```
find /data -type f \( -name "stdout" -o -name "stderr" \) -size +1000M -print
```

Sometimes we search the files on folder with `30G` size, and this takes time as `30min` or longer then that.

Since this find command is part of bash script, I want to know if we can do the search faster?

Comment: When you say you search a directory that is 30 GB, what does that mean? Does it mean that it has a single 30 GB file in it, or that it has millions of very small files?  Anything you do on directories with millions of files in them will be slow, this is why it's often better to sort files into subdirectories, or sub-sub-directories. (this depends on what filesystem is in use though)

Comment: As a benchmark, my 10-year-old Laptop with HDD can `find -size -print` about 9.3 million files in 30 minutes. Directory structure should not have a huge influence on the rate, as find traverses directories in raw order anyway. A directory tree with a rational naming convention will of course hugely improve location of specific files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`find /data -type f \( -name "stdout" -o -name "stderr" \) -size +1000M -print` is probably very close to the fastest you can do using common shell scripting tools. The size of the individual files is not relevant, because it is recorded separately from the contents. That is, `find` doesn't actually *count* the number of bytes in each file to check whether it's big enough. The bottleneck for this command is very likely the number of files, as [mentioned by @Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/634717/find-search-huge-files-in-short-time#comment1188713_634717), or some other part of the script.

If you're allowed to reveal the source code I would suggest asking on the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).